# Images get scaled and blurry

Tags: html, css, image, scale

I am try to create a div with an navigation bar image, yet the image get scaled up and becomes blurry.
In the picture you can see the original navbar overlayed in photoshop over the one that the website renders. What do you think might be the issue?

[image]

```
<div id="TopCenter" style="width: 70%; background-color: #0F1841; 
top: 0px; position: absolute; height: 90px; left: 30%; 
background-image: url(navbar.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position:left center; "></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It happpens, because you are using a width and height that is probably larger than the original image, so that's why it loses quality.

Comment: But there is no `background-size` specified in what we have been shown, so why should it scale in any way in the first place?

Comment: He is using a 90px height and position absolute.

Comment: No, I tried different ways, 90px is the original height of the image.

Comment: What about the width of 70%?